# how to add value to a progress bar while using a timer to reduce it

Tags: c#, forms, timer, progress-bar

I am creating a game where I have 3 characters. In the user interface I use progress bars to show the status of the characters' *health* and *energy*.

When the gamer starts the game it is suppose to automatically decrease the value shown in the progress bar by 10, once every second, using a timer.

When the user hits a button it should add 5 to the progress bar.

I do not know how to do it can anyone help me or get me started with some code???

Comment: What have you already tried ? Show that code

Comment: @user3185569 i do not know how to do it or begin that why i asked.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have the object `progressBar` and a variable `counter` which initially is 0 and decreases by 10 every second. Then you have a function `increaseCounter(int value)` which increases the counter by a `value`.

```
increaseCounter(int value) {
    counter += value;
}

progressBar.value = counter;

if (buttonClick) {
    increaseCounter(5);
}
```

If you want a more detailed answer, you need to ask more detailed question